# What is the default value for Options in Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-http-server, directory-listing, configure

I wonder if the Indexes option is enabled or not. For my website, it seems the directory index is disabled because visiting http://example.com/dir/ returns 403 forbidden. But I do not remember I added an "Option -Indexes" in the apache configuration file or in the .htaccess file. So I think maybe the Indexes is turned off by default in Apache 2.4? But this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/418308/why-is-options-includes-indexes-enabled-by-default-in-apache) says it is enabled by default. Can anybody give me an authority link about the default value of Options? And how to know the current value and the default value of Options? Thanks!

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options I don't know if this can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) in Apache 2.3.11 and above the default is `Options FollowSymlinks` (previously it was `Options None`). This means that all the other options are disaled by default.

Also, please note that even if `Index` is enabled, you still need [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) for it to work.